# How to do I get at my frontend on Heroku? The backend is up & running

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku, express

I finally got my node/express & mongodb running on Heroku...but how do I get at my frontend?

I am most familiar with a localHost setup, where I simply open my index.html, running localHost servers with MAMP..

When I load myapp.herokuapp.com, I see a JSON of my MongoDB docs (currently empty)

```
{
  "docs": []
}
```

And when I go to myapp.heroku.com/index.html I get my 404 error..

```
Where.. 404
```

This all makes sense, according to my express code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    getAll(res);

});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {

    res.send("Where.. 404", 404);

});
```

How do I get to my index.html frontend? *Is there any more code that would be helpful to see..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what app.use() calls do you have?

In particular, if you want to serve static .html files you need to add something along these lines (assuming your static file are located in the `./public` sub-dir):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Further details: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use